# TcpClient Read() IOException error code 10060

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm writing a TCP client to communicate with an external device, which involves sending a command then reading a response back. I've created a basic, working example from [this MS example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0), which issues a `stream.Write()` followed by a `stream.Read()`. Using this, I get a complete response back. (Responses will be no more than a few hundred bytes long).

I always thought it was wrong to assume one `Read()` would always return the full response, and it should instead be called repeatedly within a loop until it returns 0 (bytes read). However when I do this, the first call to Read() returns the complete response, and the second Read() throws an IOException, inner SocketException error code 10060 ("*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*").

I've seen some example code online that treats this specific exception/error code as though `Read()` returned 0, but I'm not sure if this is more of a hack, and whether there is a better approach?

Comment: Your assumption is correct: you cannot assume any correspondence between writes to the output network stream at one end of the connection and reads from the input network stream at the other end. In particular, data passed in a single invocation of the output network stream’s Write() method at the sender can be spread across multiple invocations of the input network stream’s Read() method at the other end; and a single Read() may return data passed in multiple Write()s.

Comment: Do you know anything about the response of the device (length, ending "token")?

Comment: There is no guarantee with TCP that you will ALWAYS get data in one chunk .  windows uses timers to move data and there is always a possibility that a message can get split any place between sender and receiver.  I proper application for any serial communications make sure the receive end can determine where the message ends.  So with ASCII data you usually terminate a message with a know character that is not inside the actual data.  Or with either ASCII or binary proceed the message with a byte count.  You can also use fix size messages.

Answer (score 0):

The NetworkStream's `Read()` method returns 0 if the connection is closed, *not* if there was nothing for it to read. The NetworkStream does however expose a `DataAvailable` bool property, and the way to go seems to be something like this:

```
do
{
   var bytesRead = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  
   // Append buffer to wherever
} 
while (_stream.DataAvailable)
```

I have found this approach to work in my scenario.

Comment: DataAvailable = true means that there are data to read in the stream buffer. But it can happen a time frame during which it is false because new data doesn't yet arrived.